# Reading WFS layer with sf::st_read. Is it possible to apply a filter along with the request?

Tags: r, wfs, sf

I'd like to read a large WFS layer in R. But since I don't need the entire layer, I'd like to filter it by some value in the attribute table. I know how to read the entire WFS layer with `sf::st_read`. Is there a way to do this filtering upon layer request? I tried using the `where` option in `st_read` but could not figure out how that works.

I can work with other R packages if needed.

Here is a simple reprex of what I'm trying to do.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 7.0.0
library(ggplot2)

wfs_url <- 'WFS:https://geoservicos.ibge.gov.br/geoserver/ows'
lyr <- 'CCAR:BC250_2017_Unidade_Federacao_A'

br_states <- st_read(dsn = wfs_url,
                     layer = lyr)
#> Reading layer `CCAR:BC250_2017_Unidade_Federacao_A' from data source `WFS:https://geoservicos.ibge.gov.br/geoserver/ows' using driver `WFS'
#> Simple feature collection with 27 features and 9 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTISURFACE
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -73.98318 ymin: -33.75118 xmax: -28.84777 ymax: 5.269508
#> geographic CRS: SIRGAS 2000

br_states <- st_read(dsn = wfs_url,
                     layer = lyr)
#> Reading layer `CCAR:BC250_2017_Unidade_Federacao_A' from data source `WFS:https://geoservicos.ibge.gov.br/geoserver/ows' using driver `WFS'
#> Simple feature collection with 27 features and 9 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTISURFACE
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -73.98318 ymin: -33.75118 xmax: -28.84777 ymax: 5.269508
#> geographic CRS: SIRGAS 2000

head(br_states)
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 9 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTISURFACE
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -73.98318 ymin: -33.75118 xmax: -49.69163 ymax: 5.269508
#> geographic CRS: SIRGAS 2000
#>                             gml_id id_objeto              nome nomeabrev
#> 1 BC250_2017_Unidade_Federacao_A.1         1 Rio Grande do Sul      <NA>
#> 2 BC250_2017_Unidade_Federacao_A.2         2          Amazonas      <NA>
#> 3 BC250_2017_Unidade_Federacao_A.3         3              Acre      <NA>
#> 4 BC250_2017_Unidade_Federacao_A.4         4          Rondônia      <NA>
#> 5 BC250_2017_Unidade_Federacao_A.5         5           Roraima      <NA>
#> 6 BC250_2017_Unidade_Federacao_A.6         6             Amapá      <NA>
#>   geometriaaproximada sigla geocodigo id_produtor id_elementoprodutor
#> 1                 Não    RS        43      250000                  NA
#> 2                 Não    AM        13      250000                  NA
#> 3                <NA>    AC        12      250000                  NA
#> 4                <NA>    RO        11      250000                  NA
#> 5                <NA>    RR        14      250000                  NA
#> 6                <NA>    AP        16      250000                  NA
#>                             geom
#> 1 MULTISURFACE (POLYGON ((-53...
#> 2 MULTISURFACE (POLYGON ((-67...
#> 3 MULTISURFACE (POLYGON ((-68...
#> 4 MULTISURFACE (POLYGON ((-60...
#> 5 MULTISURFACE (POLYGON ((-60...
#> 6 MULTISURFACE (POLYGON ((-50...

ggplot(br_states) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

```r
# I can filter the data once I've downloaded it
ggplot(br_states[br_states$sigla == 'SP',]) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

```r
# How can I filter it before the WFS request?
# Is there a way to filter inside st_read
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Just found out the correct syntax to the `where` option in `st_read`. I looks like I have to use **single quotes** around the text to be searched for. And I have the habit of using single quotes for the entire string and double quotes elsewhere.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 7.0.0
wfs_url <- 'WFS:https://geoservicos.ibge.gov.br/geoserver/ows'
lyr <- 'CCAR:BC250_2017_Unidade_Federacao_A'
# Filtering WFS upon reques
# this DOES NOT WORK
br_states <- st_read(dsn = wfs_url,
                     layer = lyr,
                     query = 'select * from 
                     BC250_2017_Unidade_Federacao_A where sigla = "SP"')
#> Warning in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet, : GDAL
#> Error 1: "SP" not recognised as an available field.
#> Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet, : Query execution failed, cannot open layer.

# THIS WORKS
br_states <- st_read(dsn = wfs_url,
                     layer = lyr,
                     query = "select * from 
                     BC250_2017_Unidade_Federacao_A where sigla = 'SP'")
#> Reading layer `CCAR:BC250_2017_Unidade_Federacao_A' from data source `WFS:https://geoservicos.ibge.gov.br/geoserver/ows' using driver `WFS'
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 9 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTISURFACE
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -53.11449 ymin: -25.31159 xmax: -44.16318 ymax: -19.78263
#> geographic CRS: SIRGAS 2000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: The single quote / double quote issue here follows SQL logic, where single and double quotes are not as interchangeable as in R itself. Should this be an inconvenience for you I believe you can use an escape character instead - something along the lines of `'select blablabla where sigla = \'SP\';'` - note the slash escaping the single quotes around SP.  I don't have your data though, so I can't test and be 100% certain.

Comment: I always remember in SQL its "Single for Strings, Double for Data" so an expression like `WHERE "x" = 'this'` is referring to column `X` in the table data and the literal string `"this"`. Double quotes aren't needed much (one case is if you have spaces in your column names...)